# How to calculate a YTD based on the Month short

Tags: ssas, cube

I have hierarchy: Month,Monthshort and Year-Quarter-Month under TimeDim Dimension,a scope is available like below to calculate YearToDate(YTD)
Scope([TimeDim].[Year - Quarter - Month].[Month].members, [TimeDim].[Month].Members);

YTD:

```
([TimeDim].[YTD]=   
          Sum(                
        CrossJoin(
            {[Time Calculation].[Current Period]},                  
            PeriodsToDate([TimeDim].[Year - Quarter - Month].[Year],                  
                [Timedim].[Year - Quarter - Month].CurrentMember
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Month will be in format YYYY-MM fullname(eg: 2017-10 October) and Month short will be MMM(Oct). If I calculate YTD on the measure based on month it works fine,
 How to calculate YTD based on Month Short? Do I require to create new scope to calulate YTD based on Month short? I am new to SSAS. Please help

Comment: I don't quite understand your question but is this SSAS tabular or SSAS Multidimensional? What version?

Comment: SSAS Multidimentional. My need is to create a accumulated calculation on a measure.  like below table, 
 
  Jan Feb Mar--Dec
 
Month   10  10  10 --10
Acc Month 10  20  30 --120

Comment: What is a members list for "Month short" hierarchy? Only 12 members (Jan...Dec) or Jan-17, Feb-17..., Jan-18, Feb-18... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created below scope for YTD with month short. Thus solved the problem.

```
Scope([Time Year Month].[Year].members,[Time Year Month].[Year - Month].[Month Short].members);          
-- accumulated YTD CALCULATIONS 
  ([Time Calculation].[YTD]=         
        SUM(                
            CrossJoin(
                {[Time Calculation].[Current Period]},                  
                PeriodsToDate([Time Year Month].[Year - Month].[Year]
                )
            )
        )

    ); 
End Scope;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this requires new SCOPE.

Because current scope contains Year "anchor" here: `[TimeDim].[Year - Quarter - Month].[Year]`.

**Answer will be updated once all additional questions answered**

Comment: I created below scope for YTD with month short. Thus solved the problem.Scope([Time Year Month].[Year].members,[Time Year Month].[Year - Month].[Month Short].members);          
-- accumulated YTD CALCULATIONS 
  ([Time Calculation].[YTD]=         
        SUM(                
            CrossJoin(
                {[Time Calculation].[Current Period]},                  
                PeriodsToDate([Time Year Month].[Year - Month].[Year]
                )
            )
        )
       
    ); 
End Scope;